# How to pass parameters to a script processed by ts-node

Tags: ts-node

I just started ts-node utilizing. It is the a very convenient tool. Run time looks clear. But it does not work for CLI solutions. I can not pass arguments into a script compiled.

```
ts-node --preserve-symlinks src/cli.ts -- printer:A
```

It does not work. I am asking for a help.

Answer (score 27):

You did not provide your script, so I can only guess at how you are extracting the arguments. This is how I have made it work with my own test script `args.ts`:

```
const a = process.argv[2];
const b = process.argv[3];
const c = process.argv[4];
console.log(`a: '${a}', b: '${b}', c: '${c}'`);
```

Called from `package.json` like this:

```
"scripts": {
   "args": "ts-node ./args.ts -- 4 2 printer:A"
}
```

This will give me output like this:

```
a: '4', b: '2', c: 'printer:A'
```

Answer (score 12):

command

```
ts-node ./test.ts hello stackoverflow
```

ts file

```
console.log("testing: >>", process.argv[2], process.argv[3]);
```

output

```
$ testing: >> hello stackoverflow
```

Happy coding

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
node --preserve-symlinks -r ts-node/register src/cli.ts printer:A
```

Answer (score 4):

**`NODE_OPTIONS`**

For the case of node options, in addition to `-r ts-node/register` mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60162828/895245 they now also mention in the docs the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable: https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/configuration/#node-flags

```
NODE_OPTIONS='--trace-deprecation --abort-on-uncaught-exception' ts-node ./index.ts
```

A quick test with:

main.ts

```
(async () => { throw 'asdf' })()
```

and run:

```
NODE_OPTIONS='--unhandled-rejections=strict' ts-node main.ts
echo $?
```

which gives `1` as expected.

Tested on Node v14.16.0, ts-node v10.0.0.